# Finding and adding a word to a particular line using shell script with exact format of a file

Tags: shell

My problem is to add a username to a file, I really stuck to proceed, please help.
Problem: I am having a file called `usrgrp.dat`. The format of this file is like:

```
ADMIN:srikanth,admin  
DEV:dev1  
TEST:test1
```

I am trying to write a shell script which should give me the output like:

```
Enter group name: DEV  
Enter the username: dev2
```

My expected output is:

```
User added to Group DEV
```

If I see the contents of `usrgrp.dat`, it should now look like:

```
DEV:dev1,dev2
TEST:test1
```

And it should give me error saying `user already present` if I am trying to add already existing user in that group. I am trying this out with the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
dispgrp()
{
        groupf="/home/srikanth/scm/auths/group.dat"
        for gname in `cat $groupf | cut -f1 -d:`
        do
                echo $gname
        done
        echo "Enter the group name:"
        read grname
        for gname in `cat $groupf | cut -f1 -d:`
        do
                if [ "$grname" = "$gname" ]
                then
                        echo "Enter the username to be added"
                        read uname
                        for grname in `cat $groupf`
                        do

                                $gname="$gname:$uname"
                                exit 1
                        done
                fi
        done
}
echo "Group display"
dispgrp
```

I am stuck and need your valuable help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh
dispgrp()
{
        groupf="/home/srikanth/scm/auths/group.dat"
        tmpfile="/path/to/tmpfile"
        # you may want to pipe this to more or less if the list may be long
        cat "$groupf" | cut -f1 -d:
        echo "Enter the group name:"
        read grname
        if grep "$grname" "$groupf" >/dev/null 2>&1
        then
            echo "Enter the username to be added"
            read uname
            if ! grep "^$grname:.*\<$uname\>" "$groupf" >/dev/null 2>&1
            then
                sed "/^$grname:/s/\$/,$uname/" "$groupf" > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "$groupf"
            else
                echo "User $uname already exists in group $grname"
                return 1
            fi
        else
            echo "Group not found"
            return 1
        fi
}
echo "Group display"
dispgrp
```

You don't need to use loops when the loops are done for you (e.g. `cat`, `sed` and `grep`).

Don't use `for` to iterate over the output of `cat`.

Don't use `exit` to return from a function. Use `return`.

A non-zero exit or return code signifies an error or failure. Use `0` for normal, successful return. This is the implicit action if you don't specify one.

Learn to use `sed` and `grep`.

Since your shebang says `#!/bin/sh`, the changes I made above are based on the Bourne shell and assume POSIX utilities (not GNU versions).

Comment: thanks for your valuable suggestion, i had tried both yours and glenn's solution. When I tried to execute script as suggested by you, it hangs after accepting a username.

Comment: @Srikanth: Sorry, I had a couple of errors that are now fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help.  It got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Something like (assume your shell is bash):

```
adduser() {
    local grp="$1"
    local user="$2"
    local gfile="$3"

    if ! grep -q "^$grp:" "$gfile"; then
        echo "no such group: $grp"
        return 1
    fi

    if grep -q "^$grp:.*\\<$user\\>" "$gfile"; then
        echo "User $user already in group $grp"
    else
        sed -i "/^$grp:/s/\$/,$user/" "$gfile"
        echo "User $user added to group $grp"
    fi 
}

read -p "Enter the group name: " grp
read -p "Enter the username to be added: " user
adduser "$grp" "$user" /home/srikanth/scm/auths/group.dat
```